# Matlab, Too many input arguments Error?

Tags: matlab

I just got a problem with matlab programming. I’d like to try to call a method from a class
and my class is very simple like this

```
classdef Addition
    properties
        a;
        b;
    end

    methods
        function obj = Addition(a, b)
            obj.a = a;
            obj.b = b;
        end

        function add(c, d)
            fprintf(c + d);
        end
    end 
end
```

I initialised a and try to call the add function by

```
a = Addition(1, 2)  
a.add(2,4)
```

However, matlab gives me the error as:

> Error using Addition/add
>   Too many input arguments.

Could somebody please tell me why this strange thing happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you are defining a method in your class, you must always pass the instance `obj` as argument. See the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html).

When working with instances of classes in Matlab, the code

```
a.add(2,4)
```

is equivalent to

```
add(a, 2, 4)
```

Since you (wrongly) defined your instance method as `function add(c, d)` Matlab is detecting 3 parameters instead of 2.

Your method declaration must be `function add(obj, c, d)`.

Read a bit more about [static methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) and [instance methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html) to decide whether you need one or the other.

Since you are not using any property in your method/function `add`, it seems that you want a static method instead of an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when I use an existing class for creating another and forget to change the constructor function name as per new class name. For example in the code below, if I forget to change `OldClass` to `NewClass` under `methods()` then I get this error. Issue resolves if I correct the name.

```
classdef NewClass
    properties()
    end
    methods()
        function obj = OldClass()
        end
    end
end
```

I end up getting this error often, so thought of sharing a possible cause of this error if it helps someone.

Comment: I was getting the error due to a subtle typo in my constructor function name.